# SQL query on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find all items that are completed inside a list. I tried doing a query inside the `Todoitem` model, but it is showing `[#<Todoitem id: nil>]`
What am I doing wrong?

The query I thought goes:

`Todoitem.find_by_sql("SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM todoitems ti INNER JOIN todolists tl WHERE (ti.completed = 'true' AND ti.todolist_id = tl.id)")`

my models are like this:

```
class Todolist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, required: false
  has_many :todoitems, dependent: :destroy
end

class Todoitem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :todolist
end
```

Comment: How are you using the result of the query?

Comment: It shows in the page: Completed Todos: [#<Todoitem id: nil>] is the number of completed todos.

Comment: We need the code that render that

Comment: class Todoitem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :todolist

   def self.get_completed_todo
 Todoitem.find_by_sql("SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM todoitems ti 
  INNER JOIN todolists tl 
  WHERE (ti.completed = 'true' AND ti.todolist_id = tl.id)")
   end
end

Comment: class TodolistsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todolist, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show
    @counted_todos = Todoitem.get_completed_todo
  end

Comment: I guess your sql query is not correct. Try this: `Todoitem.find_by_sql("SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM todoitems ti INNER JOIN todolists tl ON ti.todolist_id = tl.id WHERE ti.completed = 'true'")`

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Try to use query suggested by me, but replace `find_by_sql` with `count_by_sql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all items that are in a todolist and is completed, your query will work. (I am assuming you are storing the boolean value for completed as a string since you used a string in your original query)

However, since you are only selecting`count(*) AS count_all`, you will have to look at count_all from the first element in your array like this:

```
Todoitem.find_by_sql("SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM todo....").first.count_all
```

This will return a number of completed todoitems in all todolists in total.

The more active record way of doing this would be like this:

```
Todolist.joins(:todoitems).where(todoitems:{completed:'true' }).count
```

To get the number of lists that has at least one completed todoitem, you can use:

```
Todolist.joins(:todoitems).group(:id).where(todoitems:{completed:'true' }).length
```

To find how many items that are completed in each list you can use:

```
Todolist.joins(:todoitems).group(:id).where(todoitems:{completed:'true' }).count
```

This will return a hash with the id of the list as a key, and the number of completed items as values.

To get the number of completed items in a speciffic task you can use:

```
Todolist.joins(:todoitems).where(id: id, todoitems:{completed:'true' }).count
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am actually trying to display how many completed itens in each list. For exemple: list 1 has 2 completed itens and list 2 has 5, so I want to show list 1 has 2 completed itens when I click list 1 and list 2 has 5 completed itens when I click list 2.

Comment: For that you can use `Todolist.joins(:todoitems).where(id: id, todoitems:{completed:'true' }).count`, you will have to replace the id variable with the id of the todolist

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way.

**Rails 5 - Postgresql**

In this query, it will show only `todolist` that has `todoitems`.

```
Todolist.select('todolists.id, todolists.title, count(todoitems.todolist_id) as total').joins(:todoitems).group("todolists.id")
```

Another, This will show only `todolist` that has no `todoitems` with `0` result.

```
Todolist.select('todolists.id, todolists.title, count(todoitems.todolist_id) as total').left_joins(:todoitems).group("todolists.id")
```

I hope this help you.